# php/sqlite3 database query - duplicates ignored

Tags: php, sqlite

Using single Chinese characters in my search.

`分坨坨` is my example here. The last two (`坨坨`) are completely the same - duplicates, if you will.

My first variable is $where which looks like this:

```
$where = array();

foreach ( $qtwo as $word ) {
    $where[] = "CHS LIKE '%" . $word . "%'";
}

$where = implode(' OR ', $where);
```

Which prints:

```
CHS LIKE '%分%' OR CHS LIKE '%坨%' OR CHS LIKE '%坨%'
```

(The following is not really consequential but helps to explain my variables:)

I get them into an array called $where3 - which prints like this:

```
ORDER BY CASE CHS
WHEN '分' THEN 1
WHEN '坨' THEN 2
WHEN '坨' THEN 3
```

My query looks like this:

```
{$results4 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM FOUR WHERE $where $where3
                            END;");
while ($row4 = $results4->fetchArray()) {
```

So they print in the order that they came in - and all duplicates are represented in both variables.

When I run the query though - only the first of the duplicates gets printed back (`坨`).

How can I get it to print both of the duplicates?

Comment: I don't understand the question, what is the result you are getting and what is the result you want to get?

Comment: @jeroen I want results for 分坨坨 split up individually as 分 + 坨 + 坨 but I only get results for 分 + 坨.

Comment: What do you mean with "duplicates"? Are there duplicate rows in the database?

Comment: But you are using `OR` so that is exactly the same...

Comment: @jeroen Suggestions? then?

Comment: What do you mean with *printed back*? You do `select *`, so you are getting fields back: nothing gets split up. Can you provide a few records sample data from your table, and provide which output you would expect for it?

Comment: Take the example above the problem is the duplicate expression: OR CHS LIKE '%坨%' OR CHS LIKE '%坨%' - the first one works the second gets ignored.

Comment: I don't see any example. I see an example of how you create the query, but not of the data in your table.